# Gmap Module open info window(bubble) from external link

Tags: views, 7, google-maps

Not even sure where to start.

Would like to have a menu in the sidebar that when clicking on a link will open an info window (bubble) in the Google map.

Any ideas on a jumping off point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a function that opens an existing infoWindow:

```
function triggerPopup(marker) {
  // Get the map using getMap() which needs the maps ID
  var mapID = $('.gmap').attr('id');
  var map = Drupal.gmap.getMap(mapID);
  map = map.map;
  // Get the map's current markers
  var markers = map.markers;
  // Trigger the popup for the marker passed to triggerPopup()
  google.maps.event.trigger(markers[marker], 'click');
};
```

Then you can use this function with any external link:

```
$('.your-external-link').click( function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  triggerPopup(0);
});
```

This gives you the basic idea of how you can trigger the popups, you'd need to figure out a way to associate the sidebar links with the markers - this is completely dependent on how you have everything set up.

Answer (score 0):

Start by trying existing modules.

The [Gmap](https://www.drupal.org/project/gmap) module or the [Simple Google Maps](https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_gmap) module may be a good starting point.

Comment: Yup i've got Gmap installed. I have a view that is building the map. Now i need to somehow be able to add a click event on the markers, from an external source.

Comment: Then you'll have to have a look at the google maps api and see how you can adapt what is generated thought theming to meet your needs. See : https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/map for the google maps api.